# Can someone tell me how .remove() works? Its working but I dont understand how

Tags: javascript

Well I build an expense tracker as a beginner project it is working but I added .remove() because .removeChild() was being difficult. but why does .remove() NOT remove every element with the same name in my table?
Javascript:

```
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    
    submit.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var name = document.getElementById('name');
        var amount = document.getElementById('date');
        var date = document.getElementById('amount');
        var table = document.getElementById('table');
    //-------------------------------------------------------
        var newRow = table.insertRow(-1);
        var newCell0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
        var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
        var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
        var removeCell = newRow.insertCell(3);

        var text0 = document.createTextNode(name.value);
        newCell0.appendChild(text0);
        var text1 = document.createTextNode(date.value);
        newCell1.appendChild(text1);
        var text2 = document.createTextNode(amount.value);
        newCell2.appendChild(text2);
        var btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.innerHTML = "Remove";
        removeCell.appendChild(btn);
    
        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            newCell0.remove();
            newCell1.remove();
            newCell2.remove();
            removeCell.remove();
        });
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: `newCell0` refers to the `newCell0` that is currently in scope. Not every single `newCell0` from other times the function that defined them was called.

Comment: thank you very much i did not know it was called scope <3